# scipy.minimize doesn't work. Loss doesn't decrease

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I'm working on Python to optimize some parameters with neural data.

I used scipy.optimize.minimize(BFGS method).

It's the problem that the loss is too big to decrease.
like those.

21395.738099992504
21395.738127943157
21395.738115877684
21395.738162622994
21395.738115161068
21395.738162367332
21395.738110567938
21395.73813130535
21395.738097769616
21395.738104114924
21395.73813444559

Here's my code.

```
def fit_lnp(X, y, opts):
    """
    Fits an LNP model to the data.

    Args:
        X (numpy.ndarray): Input data matrix.
        y (numpy.ndarray): Output data vector.
        opts (dict): Options for the optimizer.

    Returns:
        tuple: Tuple containing the optimized parameters and predicted values.
    """
    init = 1e-3 * np.random.randn(X.shape[0], 1).flatten()
    result = minimize(
        lambda param: do_lnp(param, X.T, y.T), init, method="BFGS", options=opts
    )
    param = result.x
    yHat = np.exp(np.dot(X.T, param)).T
    return param, yHat


def do_lnp(param, X, y):
    """
    Computes the objective function, its gradient, and the Hessian for the LNP model.

    Args:
        param (numpy.ndarray): Parameter array.
        X (numpy.ndarray): Input data matrix.
        y (numpy.ndarray): Output data vector.

    Returns:
        tuple: Tuple containing the objective function value, its gradient, and the Hessian matrix.
    """
    lamda = 1e-2
    # compute the firing rate
    u = np.dot(X, param.reshape(-1, 1))
    rate = np.exp(u)

    # start computing the Hessian
    rX = rate[:, None] * X  # equivalent to MATLAB's bsxfun(@times, rate, X)
    hessian_glm = np.dot(rX.T, X)

    # regularize term
    reg_val = (lamda / 2) * np.sum(np.exp(param) ** 2)

    # compute f, the gradient, and the hessian
    f = np.sum(rate - y * u) + reg_val
    print(f)
    df = np.dot(X.T, (rate - y))
    hessian = hessian_glm
    return f
```

Should I change the method to minimize?
How could I figure out the way to improve this optimization?

I need some help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As is, function `do_lnp` calculates the values of the function, its gradient and hessian... but returns only the function:

```
return f
```

should be replaced by

```
return f, df, hessian
```

*and* one needs to specify `jac=True, hess=True` in the call to minimize.

Alternatively, hessian and jacobian can be passed as separate functions.

See for the full description [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)

Some general tips:

- Note that you can pass additional function parameters to minimize - no need to use a lambda function.
- It is good to explore first the target function, to understand its behavior near the minimum, at least in some simple cases.
- You can try using "Nelder-Mead" as the optimization method - it is much slower, but very robust.

Comment: Thank you So much! I fixed it. Actually I'm using BFGS method, so hessian wasn't working. I specified jac=True only. and change the return as f,df.  Eventually it works now! 

However, the loss is still large. I have no idea if I have to change the optimization method or process data in another way..
Anyway, thank you so much!!!!!!!!